# Unity deploying to xcode in objective-C: how to delay launch screen in didFinishLaunching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have created a game in Unity and am deploying to an iPhone by building the project for Xcode and going from there. Unity wraps its projects up and generates the objective-C files in Xcode for you;

I have worked with Swift in the past and have always delayed my launch screens (I know this is bad practice but I am working with someone who would like the splash screen displayed for 3 seconds before the game instead just appearing briefly) by having the application `sleep` for a few seconds in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. I need to know how to do this with a Unity project generated with objective-c-

I have tried putting `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:6.0];` in the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

function in my UnityAppController.mm file, and while this seems to be the right place the splash screen is still displayed for maybe a second.

How can I delay the splash in a unity project in Xcode?

Comment: The better approach is to have your first view controller display the same image as your splash screen and then have it move to your next VC after a delay

Comment: I know, but everything is complicated by the number of files generated by Unity, etc. I will try that approach if this does not work however do you know how to delay the splash screen with sleepForTimeInterval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can implement this request in the Unity itself.

Create a 2D canvas in your first scene, and make it over everything else like this:

```
Render Mode: Screen Space - Overlay
```

Change your splash screen image texture type to Sprite like this

```
Texture Type: Sprite (2D and UI)
```

Create an UI Image and assign above sprite as Source Image to cover all screen

```
Source Image: SplashScreenImage
```

Create a start script component into canvas object like this one

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class CanvasBehaviour : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Image backgroundImage;

    void Awake() {
        StartCoroutine(RemoveBackgroundImage());
    }

    private IEnumerator RemoveBackgroundImage() 
    {
        Debug.Log("Before Waiting 3 seconds");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        backgroundImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(backgroundImage);
    }
}
```

By doing this, after splash screen, user will only see the same image so he/she will not understand that anything changed.

Since you don't block the UI Thread by making sleep, you can show some basic animation in the canvas and/or prepare your scene behind the background image.